# Adding 2 images under a single div

Tags: html, css, image

I have been trying to add two images under a single div, but they aren't displaying the way I wanted.

I want to have space between the images, which is not happening.

Here is the css,

```
.sidebarBody {
    text-align:center;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

And this is the HTML,

```
<div class='sidebarBody'>
    <img src="r.gif" />
    <img src="s.gif" />
</div>
```

Why isn't the padding working on all sides ? The second image is displayed right after the first without any space.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your css does not put any padding around the images, it only tells it to do the enclosing `<div>`. Use the following:

```
.sidebarBody img {
   text-align:center;
   padding: 5px;
}
```

This tells the browser to add a 5px padding to every image inside of `.sidebarBody` (the div class).

Comment: @Timothy Black: you can also explicitly specify the padding on one of the images:  

<img src="r.gif" style="padding-right: 5px;" />

Comment: you might need to write   padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;  or something if you are butting up images...

Comment: @sheriffderek That would still cause a 5px on one side. I think you mean - padding: 5px 0; or padding: 5px 0 5px 0;

Comment: yeah you're right - it would depend... just tossing out the full listing style-  top right bottom left -etc... when floating... sometimes you want padding or margins on only one side so that the padding in-between images or whatevers is not double... in special cases.

Comment: also - i wouldn't put styles in the <img> tag... i would (if you were going to style them differently ... make a class and add it to the img and then style it in the style sheet...

Comment: Thank you all for your help. One more thing, how do I make sure that the images come below each other and not side by side ?

Comment: can try to add `clear:both;` or add a `<br />` after each image